# Macro to only paste values if they are also found in a master list

Tags: excel, vba

I have several columns of dates, which I have distilled down into one master list, that contains all the dates each list has in common. Therefore any value in this list MUST be found in all the other columns.

I have several tables of data, across multiple sheets (which has dates in one column and values in the adjacent one), the columns of dates are fed from each table of data in these sheets, so these sheets may contain dates that are not found in the master list.

I want to copy and paste into adjacent columns, on each of these sheets, all the dates and their corresponding values that are contained in the master list.

Example (all listed on separate sheets, in range F13:GX)
(use sheet names of List 1, List 2, List 3 etc). All the sheets in the workbook will contain a list, apart from one called "Cover").
List 1

```
22/12/2012 1
23/12/2012 2
24/12/2012 3 
27/12/2012 4
28/12/2012 5
```

List 2

```
22/12/2012 2
23/12/2012 10
24/12/2012 11
28/12/2012 15
```

List 3

```
22/12/2012 2
23/12/2012 17
28/12/2012 22
29/12/2012 33
```

I want it to copy and paste the dates and values for

```
22/12/2012 
23/12/2012 
28/12/2012
```

for each list, and paste them into the range H13:I15

so i would have as the desired output.

List 1

```
22/12/2012 1 22/12/2012 1
23/12/2012 2 23/12/2012 2
24/12/2012 3 28/12/2012 5 
27/12/2012 4
28/12/2012 5
```

List 2

```
22/12/2012 2  22/12/2012 2
23/12/2012 10 23/12/2012 10
24/12/2012 11 28/12/2012 15
28/12/2012 15
```

List 3

```
22/12/2012 2  22/12/2012 2
23/12/2012 17 23/12/2012 17
28/12/2012 22 28/12/2012 22
29/12/2012 33
```

There would be no blanks when values are skipped.

Comment: you have one master list and number of sheets to compare. So 1. Are all these sheets in one workbook including the master list? 2. Will you be having more than 3 sheets to compare (to say you want the number of sheets to be dynamic)?

Comment: ... You could write a fairly simple macro using the `Match()` function against the master list to find out if the date is there for each row in a loop. If it is, then you copy that row's data into the list for that sheet.

Comment: yea my macro writing is a little rusty. I can see through the logic, but couldn't code it for toffee. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to use formulas rather than a macro.

For the example given, enter this formula in H3 of every "List" sheet:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(MasterList,ROW()-ROW(F$13)+1),"")`

and this one in I3:

`=IF(H13="","",INDEX(G:G,MATCH(H13,F:F,0)))`

Copy/fill the formula down as far as necessary.

`MasterList` is a Named Range referring to the master list of dates. A dynamic example, assuming the master list starts in cell A1 of a sheet named "Master" (with nothing else in the column), would be:

`=Master!$A$1:INDEX(Master!A:A,COUNTA(Master!A:A))`

You could, if so inclined, insert this directly into the first formula above.

**Note:** I kept the second formula above as simple as possible. As a result, it will break if there are any dates (or number equivalents) in the range F1:F12 matching the master list.

If you *really* want/need a macro solution the following "fairly simple" one should do the trick:

```
Public Sub PasteMasterDates()

  Dim fn As WorksheetFunction: Set fn = Application.WorksheetFunction

  Dim wkstWorkSheet As Worksheet
  Dim varMasterArray As Variant
  Dim varDatesArray As Variant
  Dim varValuesArray As Variant
  Dim lngMasterUBound As Long
  Dim lngMasterIndex As Long
  Dim lngMatchIndex As Long
  Dim varNumberFormat As Variant

  With Worksheets("Master")
    With Range(.Range("A1:B1"), .Range("A1").End(xlDown))
      varNumberFormat = .Cells(1).NumberFormat
      varMasterArray = fn.Transpose(fn.Transpose(.Cells))
      lngMasterUBound = UBound(varMasterArray, 1)
    End With
  End With
  For Each wkstWorkSheet In Application.Worksheets
    With wkstWorkSheet
      If .Name Like "List *" Then
        With Range(.Range("F13"), .Range("F13").End(xlDown))
          varDatesArray = fn.Transpose(.Cells)
          varValuesArray = fn.Transpose(.Cells.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1))
          For lngMasterIndex = 1 To lngMasterUBound
            lngMatchIndex = fn.Match(varMasterArray(lngMasterIndex, 1), varDatesArray, 0)
            varMasterArray(lngMasterIndex, 2) = varValuesArray(lngMatchIndex)
          Next lngMasterIndex
          With .Cells.Offset(ColumnOffset:=2).Resize(RowSize:=lngMasterUBound)
            .NumberFormat = varNumberFormat
            .Resize(ColumnSize:=2) = varMasterArray
          End With
        End With
      End If
    End With
  Next wkstWorkSheet

End Sub
```

**Important points:**

1. The master list is assumed to be in a sheet named "Master" as per the formula solution above.
2. Whilst this now works even if there are dates/numbers in the range F1:F12 matching the master list, it *will* break if rows are inserted above, or columns to the left of, F13. Until you fix the macro, that is.
3. Adding/inserting dates into the "List" sheets, or adding more of these sheets, is automatically allowed for.
4. The date format for the pasted values is copied from the first date in the master list.
5. For speed reasons, the sheet data is loaded into VBA arrays. All calculations are done on these arrays before writing the results back to the sheet.

**Note:** Since I presume you are already running a macro to generate the master list (doing so via formulas only would be difficult if not impossible), you could modify my macro to build the master list, like you currently do, before using it.
Alternatively, you could build and use it without actually saving it to a sheet. I would suggest loading all the "List" sheet data into an array of arrays, at the same time as building the master list using a dictionary. Then you loop over the array of arrays again, this time using the master list to generate the results.

**EDIT:**

This version of the macro allows for dates in the master list that are not in every one of the other lists.

```
Public Sub PasteMasterDates2()

  Const cMasterSheetName As String = "Master"
  Const cMasterStart As String = "A1"
  Const cLikeListSheetName As String = "List *"
  Const cListStart As String = "F13"

  Dim fn As WorksheetFunction: Set fn = Application.WorksheetFunction

  Dim wkstWorkSheet As Worksheet
  Dim varMasterArray As Variant
  Dim varDatesArray As Variant
  Dim varValuesArray As Variant
  Dim avarPasteDatesArray() As Double
  Dim avarPasteValuesArray() As Double
  Dim lngMasterUBound As Long
  Dim lngListUBound As Long
  Dim lngPasteUBound As Long
  Dim lngMasterIndex As Long
  Dim lngMatchIndex As Long
  Dim varNumberFormat As Variant

  With Worksheets(cMasterSheetName)
    With Range(.Range(cMasterStart), .Range(cMasterStart).End(xlDown))
      varNumberFormat = .Cells(1).NumberFormat
      varMasterArray = fn.Transpose(.Cells)
      lngMasterUBound = UBound(varMasterArray)
    End With
  End With
  For Each wkstWorkSheet In Application.Worksheets
    With wkstWorkSheet
      If .Name Like cLikeListSheetName Then
        With Range(.Range(cListStart), .Range(cListStart).End(xlDown))
          varDatesArray = fn.Transpose(.Cells)
          varValuesArray = fn.Transpose(.Cells.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1))
          lngListUBound = UBound(varDatesArray, 1)
          ReDim avarPasteDatesArray(1 To lngListUBound)
          ReDim avarPasteValuesArray(1 To lngListUBound)
          lngPasteUBound = 0
          For lngMasterIndex = 1 To lngMasterUBound
            lngMatchIndex = 0
            On Error Resume Next
            lngMatchIndex = fn.Match(varMasterArray(lngMasterIndex), varDatesArray, 0)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If lngMatchIndex _
            Then
              lngPasteUBound = lngPasteUBound + 1
              avarPasteDatesArray(lngPasteUBound) = varDatesArray(lngMatchIndex)
              avarPasteValuesArray(lngPasteUBound) = varValuesArray(lngMatchIndex)
            End If
          Next lngMasterIndex
          If lngPasteUBound _
          Then
            ReDim Preserve avarPasteDatesArray(1 To lngPasteUBound)
            ReDim Preserve avarPasteValuesArray(1 To lngPasteUBound)
            With .Cells.Offset(ColumnOffset:=2).Resize(RowSize:=lngPasteUBound)
              .NumberFormat = varNumberFormat
              .Cells = fn.Transpose(avarPasteDatesArray)
              .Offset(ColumnOffset:=1) = fn.Transpose(avarPasteValuesArray)
            End With
          End If
        End With
      End If
    End With
  Next wkstWorkSheet

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for the belated reply, I get a worksheet function error, (Unable to get the Match Property of the worksheet function class). The master list contains dates that might not be on the individual lists. I realise this is a contradiction to my question and so for that I apologise. I opted for a much lengthier master list, which can now contain some values that the other lists cant. Is there a way of making it skip to the next value if this occurs? an on error go to or similar?

Comment: An `On Error Resume Next` / `On Error GoTo 0` pair is exactly what's needed. Unfortunately, the logic of the macro was based on the assumption that every item in the master list existed in every other list. Fortunately, the changes required weren't _too_ great. New macro has been appended to answer.

Comment: This is perfect, I can't thank you enough. Sorry for messing you around.

Comment: @Cylen - You could thank me by looking up some of your older questions that you haven't accepted an answer for, and accepting an answer if it's appropriate and correct. (Now that's strange - one of them has an answer _I_ gave ;-) )